# Dependency Inversion with a List<T> in a method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, factory, dependency-inversion

How would one implement Dependency Inversion on a given class like the following code?
Problem is the function "Add" in class A, which containts the new Keyword.

I'm using Autofac for Dependency Injection.

Should I create an "IBFactory" which I register in my Autofac, or use Method Injection, or something completely else?

```cs
public class A {
   List<B> _list = new List<B>();
   ILogger _logger;

   public A(ILogger logger) {  //Depency Injection using Autofac
        _logger = logger;
   }

   public Add(object X) {
        if (X is String)
           _list.Add(new B1());
        else
           _list.Add(new B2());
   }

}

public interface B {
}

public class B1 : B {
}

public class B2 : B {
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiate `B1` and `B2` through Autofac each time you need one?

Comment: What is the return type of `Add` method?

Comment: @John Yes, based on a given argument

Comment: @ValeriuSeremet The return type doesn't matter, it's only an example

Comment: Even with dependency injection, sometimes it is also OK to just do `new B1()` or `new B2()` for instance, if implementations of B are simple data objects or leaf nodes in your application's logic there is often little benefit in faking them out and the extra layer of abstraction for the factory is just an extra layer of abstraction.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor I'm aware of that, but thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A factory delegate could be used at act as a factory for the desired types

```
public class A {
    List<B> _list = new List<B>();
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly Func<B1> factory1;
    private readonly Func<B2> factory2;

    public A(ILogger logger, Func<B1> factory1, Func<B2> factory2) {  
        //Depency Injection using Autofac
        this.logger = logger;
        this.factory1 = factory1;
        this.factory2 = factory2;
   }

   public Add(object X) {
        if (X is String)
           _list.Add(factory1());
        else
           _list.Add(factory2());
   }
}
```

> If type `T` is registered with the container, Autofac will automatically resolve dependencies on `Func<T>` as factories that create `T` instances through the container.

#### Reference [Autofac: Delegate Factories](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html#delegate-factories)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I'm looking for